# Error when adding checkbox programatically to datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms

When using this code :

```
GridView1.Columns.Add(new TemplateField());
BoundField b = new BoundField();
GridView1.Columns.Add(b);
b.DataField = "ID";

//Add checkbox
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn doWork = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
doWork.HeaderText = "Include Dog";
doWork.FalseValue = "0";
doWork.TrueValue = "1";
GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, doWork);

GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have no problem adding any of the columns except the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`, where I get this error message:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn'
>   to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says: `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` is a windows forms control. You cannot add that to a web forms DataGrid.

Have a look at the namespaces in the error message:

> cannot convert from '**System.Windows.Forms**.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn' to '**System.Web.UI.WebControls**.DataControlField'

Comment: Thanks.  I also found another way to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006106/how-to-add-the-checkbox-field-in-gridview/18149273#18149273

Answer (score 0):

This will work with the datagrid view:

```
GridView1.Columns.Add(doWork);
```

There is also another method for this:

```
Gridview1.Columns.Add(doWork, "Include Dog");
```

Which allows you to define the header as you are adding it